# Python script not working after patch upgrade of outlook to win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 14.0

Tags: python, outlook-2010

I have few python script interacting with Microsoft Outlook 2010 without any issues.

But after applying the patch to outlook getting all these errors on the python 2.7 scripts ( which were running fine since last 3 years).

The complete error is 
**AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'SaveASFile'**

Here is the Code

for msg in messages:

```
  attachments = msg.Attachments
  attachment = attachments.Item(1)      
  attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join('c:\\EDIT', 'outlookAttach.txt'))
```

Thanks in advance.
-Sway

Comment: The Error is AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library.Attachme
nt instance at 0x75046408>' object has no attribute 'SaveASFile'

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I changed the attribute name to 'SaveAsFile' from 'SaveASFile'

I know it's funny. But, it worked for me!

Also make sure you specify the type of attachment that you are downloading. In your case the attachment **should** be txt type.

This is my code :

```
att=msg.Attachments
attachment = att.Item(1)
attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join('C:\Users\Harish\Desktop', 'outlookAttach.msg'))
```

In my case the attachment was and eml file. So, it's working fine.

Or, you can do this:

```
attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join('C:\Users\Harish\Desktop', attachment.FileName))
```

It works too

Hope it helped

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for this attribute error is because your COM-server has shifted from late-binding (dynamic) to early binding (static).

- In Late Binding, whenever a method is called, the object is queried for the method and if it succeeds, then the call can be made.
- In Early Binding, the information of the object model is determined in advance from type information supplied by the object call. Early binding makes uses MakePy. Also, early binding is case sensitive.

There are two ways to fix this issue:

1. Use the dynamic module to force your code to work in a late-bound oriented way. Example use:

   ```
   "win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch()" instead of "win32com.client.Dispatch()"
   ```
2. Use camelcase sensitive keywords for the early bound oriented way. Example use:

   ```
   "excel.Visible()" instead of "excel.VISIBLE()" or "excel.visible()"
   ```

In your case, as he said to use:

```
"attachment.SaveAsFile" instead of "attachment.SaveASFile"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Changing to camelcase worked for me. From ns.createRecipient() to ns.CreateRecipient(). However, the dynamic solution did not.